# How to change sensor information on device in android

Tags: android, android-sensors

Can anybody tell me how to change the sensor information on a device in Android?

Is it possible to change the sensor information programmatically?

If yes, can anybody provide a tutorial for this?

Comment: Define : "Change Sensor Information"

Comment: change raw data that's received in the callback ?

Comment: @Kedarnath if user state of sensor  is walking need to change driving

Comment: It's read only. Mean you can get some raw data from sensors and do whatever you want, but you can't give information to sensors.. Just google and you will find a lot of info on how to use sensors in android.

Comment: @Daler is it possible to set mock sensor in device like mock location ?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html.. I'm not a pro in sensors but you can read in official link which I've provided, Sensors have only getMethods.. However the first link is a library with Sensors emulations.. probably it's what you want